# facebook wall post from wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress

How to post on facebook account wall when any blog post made from wordpress.

**I allready tried with various wordpress plugin like "wordbook", "wordbooker"** etc but none of them working fine........ any idea or alternative way?

Comment: This is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Twitter Tools plugin and then link your twitter account to your Facebook account. I use it all the time, plus you get the added benefit of Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a plugin for that matter, you can check out the development version right over here: http://kovshenin.com/public/facebook-feeder-alpha.tar.gz

It doesn't have a funky user interface, but it does post stuff to Facebook assuming you have a facebook developer account and a facebook app registered. Look at the posts on my Facebook profile: http://facebook.com/kovshenin (ones marked via kovshenin.com) - they're generated via this plugins.

P.S. It doesn't to that automatically, but you can send it to FB when the post is published. Shouldn't require much time to automate it, but I'd like to customize things before sending anything anywhere.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

P.S. PHP programming skills required to use this plugin.